# How to get RTL on Less

Tags: css, less

Hey guys I don't much experience with RTL Styles and I would really appreciate a help here.

I have this nested .less style. How can I detect if it's RTL and properly change 2 values?
I tried this but it doesn't work. Any tips?

I just need to change the *margin-left* and *margin-right* property values for RTL.

Thanks

```
#backdrop {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;

    .content {
        padding: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 700px;
        height: 400px;
        background: #FFF;
        border-radius: 10px;
        overflow: scroll;
        margin-left: -225px;

        @media (max-width:768px) {
            margin-left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90vh;
        }
    } & {
        html {
            [dir=rtl] & {
                #backdrop {
                    .content {
                        margin-left: 0;
                        margin-right: -255px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the RTL style is a separate HTML file from the LTR one, then just add a specific class for the RTL element you want to edit, for example, put `class="rtl__style"`
on the element, and you can style that the way you want.

Comment: Hey @sham thanks... but is there a way to do that without specifying a new class? Just add like a media query?